# Cannot find 'radius' in scope

Tags: swift, find

Ball.swift

```
protocol BallProtocol {
    init(color: UIColor,
         radius: Int,
         coordinates:(x: Int, y: Int))
}

public class Ball: UIView, BallProtocol {
    required public init(color: UIColor,
                         radius: Int,
                         coordinates: (x: Int, y: Int)) {
        super.init(frame: CGRect(x: coordinates.x,
                                 y: coordinates.y,
                                 width: radius * 2,
                                 height: radius * 2))
        self.layer.cornerRadius = self.bounds.width / 2.0
        self.backgroundColor = color
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

SquareArea.swift

```
protocol SquareAreaProtocol {
    init(size: CGSize,
         color: UIColor)
    func setBalls(withColors: [UIColor],
                  andRadius: Int)
}

public class SquareArea: UIView, SquareAreaProtocol {
    private var balls: [Ball] = []
    private var animator: UIDynamicAnimator?
    private var snapBehavior: UISnapBehavior?
    private var collisionBehavior: UICollisionBehavior
    
    required public init(size: CGSize,
                         color: UIColor) {
        collisionBehavior = UICollisionBehavior(items: [])
        super.init(frame: CGRect(x: 0,
                                 y: 0,
                                 width: size.width,
                                 height: size.height))
        self.backgroundColor = color
        collisionBehavior.setTranslatesReferenceBoundsIntoBoundary(with: UIEdgeInsets(top: 1,
                                                                                      left: 1,
                                                                                      bottom: 1,
                                                                                      right: 1))
        animator = UIDynamicAnimator(referenceView: self)
        animator?.addBehavior(collisionBehavior)
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    public func setBalls(withColors ballsColor:[UIColor],
                         andRadius:Int) {
        for (index, oneBallColor) in ballsColor.enumerated() {
            let coordinateX = 10 + (2 * radius) * index
            let coordinateY = 10 + (2 * radius) * index
            let ball = Ball(color: oneBallColor,
                            radius: radius,
                            coordinates: (x: coordinateX, y: coordinateY))
            self.addSubview(ball)
            self.balls.append(ball)
            collisionBehavior.addItem(ball)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы не указали параметр `radius`

```
public func setBalls(withColors ballsColor:[UIColor], andRadius radius:Int)
```